# How to pass multiple QuerySet values into filter()

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter

I got 3 models, one with auctions, second with watchlist, third with users

```
class Auctions(models.Model):
    lot = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank = True)
    startBid = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank = True)

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    watchlist = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank = True)
```

Views:

```
def addToWatchlist(request, id):
    print(id, "ID")
    user = request.user
    watchlist = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = user, watchlist = id)
    data = list(watchlist)
    if data == []:
        createWatchList = Watchlist(
            user = request.user,
            watchlist = id
        )
        createWatchList.save()
    else:
        watchlist.delete()

    return redirect('listing', id=id)
    

def watchlist(request):
    id = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    auctions = Auctions.objects.filter(id = id)
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
        "auctions": auctions
    })
```

I receive an error "ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."
Can someone explain how to pass multiple QuerySet values into filter()
As a result, I need all auctions, that's a match the watchlist
Thank you!

Comment: Where did you use the *slicing operator*? Can you add the full error traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
watchlist_id = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = request.user).values('id')
auctions = Auctions.objects.filter(id__in = watchlist_id).all()
```

Here we first filter watchlist_id and then it contain (`id__in`) in auctions table.

Comment: Thank you, it works, just only changes values('id') to values('watchlist')